# What is the word for: "transform into words"?

Tags: single-word-requests

In my essay, I want to use a phrase that would best express *'the act of  transforming real events into words.'* I know that initally sounds a bit awkward, but I will give the context to clarify this.

> News feed, social media, and television where many sought their repose were only repeating what was going on

So, instead of writing *repeating* I want to use something like *liquidify* or *transcribe.* But both these words do not really connotate the idea I want to give. I want to say that these news feeds were just transforming what was outside into words, which made people feel even more besieged.

Any suggestions?

Also, is the question mark in my question text placed correctly?

Comment: You don't transform events into words: you translate events into words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One verb may be [**verbalize**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/verbalize):

> to express in words:
>   *He couldn't verbalize his feelings*.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what word you are looking for here, so here are a few suggestions.

**[report](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/report)** - Give a spoken or written account of something that one has observed, heard, done, or investigated.

> News feeds **report** world events

**[document](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/document)** - Record (something) in written, photographic, or other form

> Newspapers **document** world events

**[describe](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/describe)** - Give a detailed account in words of

> Reporters **describe** events that they witness

[en.oxforddictionaries.com]

Answer (score 0):

to **[translate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/translate)** events into words

> **1.** a: to bear, remove, or change from one place, state, form, or appearance to another
>   b: *transfer*, transform translate ideas into action

Merriam-Webster

Comment: @Mari-Lou translate is in red, that makes it stand out and replaces exactly the OP's word.

Comment: Whatever. It was a very short phrase so I doubt it causes any confusion.

Comment: Whatever.... Just to be clear, the fact I edited and highlighted the answer in red was because the post did look confusing to me. Why not post this answer in the (slightly) older question?

Comment: _translate_ fits very well, but due to the word limit, I would go for _verbalize_

Answer (score 0):

How about "describe"?

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/describe

> to represent or give an account of in words

In another context, you could also use "articulate," though that doesn't seem appropriate to your example.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the answer given by oerkelens is the best option so far. I would agree with ***verbalize***.

Even though this is for a single word request, consider the phrase ***put a name to it***. This can be used in the context of something unmentionable occurring, and calling it for what it is to the horror of the listener. For example:

> What he did to that girl is unspeakable. I can't believe the media can just ***put a name to it*** so casually as if they're just words. It was absolutely horrific, I can't bring myself to speak of it.

Comment: That doesn't really suit the example sentence.

Comment: "News feed, social media, and television where many sought their repose were only putting a name to what was going on" -- how not so?

Comment: Because they're not ["putting a name to"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/put_a_name_to) it.